# Why does git keep recreating a branch with a forced update?

Tags: git, github

Whenever I do a fetch I get a notice from Git saying it has received a forced update and it says a branch is new. It does this for every fetch. I am wondering why this happens, and how I can keep it from happening (meaning fix it). I tried `rm .git/refs/remotes/MWNG`, but that had no effect.

```
$ git fetch MWNG
From github.com:MWNG/multikanal.epi7.mysite
 + 022873b...ecaa5df Feature/2005-registrering-sunnhetsbonus -> MWNG/Feature/2005-registrering-sunnhetsbonus  (forced update)
 * [new branch]      feature/2005-registrering-sunnhetsbonus -> MWNG/feature/2005-registrering-sunnhetsbonus
 * [new branch]      feature/azure-rest-api -> MWNG/feature/azure-rest-api

$ git fetch MWNG
From github.com:MWNG/multikanal.epi7.mysite
 + 022873b...ecaa5df Feature/2005-registrering-sunnhetsbonus -> MWNG/Feature/2005-registrering-sunnhetsbonus  (forced update)
 * [new branch]      feature/2005-registrering-sunnhetsbonus -> MWNG/feature/2005-registrering-sunnhetsbonus
 * [new branch]      feature/azure-rest-api -> MWNG/feature/azure-rest-api
```

As you can see from the above output there are probably two distict, but related problems. One branch has a forced push update and the other not, while both are supposedly new branches  *every* time.

Comment: Looks like case-sensitive branch names issue. `Feature/2005-*` is creating a new branch `feature/2005-*` in local .git/refs. Can you verify if the new branches listed here, are in `git branch` locally?

Comment: I think you are definitely on to something, as that reminded me I experienced this before. Oh, the joys of having a case tolerant file system on Mac...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [acsrujan noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39578431/why-does-git-keep-recreating-a-branch-with-a-forced-update#comment66467267_39578431), the issue has to do with case-folding.

The problem can be boiled down to two parts:

1. Git's branch names are case-sensitive.
2. Git's branch names are *sometimes* stored via file-names, which on *some* systems, are (sometimes) *not* case-sensitive.

This causes Git to confuse itself on such systems, precisely at the point at which they are stored via file-names: they become case-*in*sensitive (though, at least, typically case-*preserving*) at that point, even though they are case-sensitive elsewhere.  Now Git doesn't know if it's one branch, or two different branches.

Git may eventually need a general mechanism to deal with this and other issues on MacOS HFS+ and Windows file systems that are set by default to case-preserving-but-insensitive modes (other OSes, including Linux, can do this as well, but don't by default).  Until then, your simplest—or maybe I should say least-confusing—method for dealing with this issue is to use or borrow a case-sensitive system (such as a Linux machine), deal with the colliding branches there in all the usual ways, and update them from there to the server.

If that's not available, there *is* a relatively simple way to fix this particular problem on a case-insensitive (Mac or Windows) client.  Note that I have not tested this.  It can also be simplified much more if you just need to discard one of the colliding branch-names (see the last paragraph).

1. Run `git fetch <remotename>`, e.g., `git fetch MWNG`.  This will bring over all the branches and drop their info into `.git/FETCH_HEAD`, which (since it's file *data*) will record all the references and their IDs.
2. Pick one of the names to change.  Let's say, in this case, you would like to replace `Feature/2005-registrering-sunnhetsbonus` with `feature/joe-used-a-bad-name` (lowercase `f`, and we're blaming Joe, whoever he is).  Find the hash ID from `FETCH_HEAD`, being careful to get the right upper/lower-case mix.  If you have a tool like `awk` you can do this:

   ```
   awk '$4 == "'\''Feature/2005-registrering-sunnhetsbonus'\''" { print $1 }' < \
       .git/FETCH_HEAD
   ```

   but it may be easiest just to view the file (using `less` or `more` or your favorite editor).
3. Use `git push` to create a new, better-named branch pointing to that same ID (which in this case will begin with `022873b`):

   ```
   git push MWNG 022873b...:refs/heads/feature/joe-used-a-bad-name
   ```

   (note: you may be able to just use the abbreviated SHA-1 ID, if it's unique.  If not, paste in the exact ID, which will definitely work.)
4. Use `git push` to *delete* the bad name:

   ```
   git push MWNG :Feature/2005-registrering-sunnhetsbonus
   ```

   (or `git push --delete MWNG Feature/2005-registrering-sunnhetsbonus`, which is a longer but more memorable way to do the same thing).  You can combine this with step 3 as long as you avoid the `--delete` flag: one `git push` with both the ID-and-new-name, and empty-string-and-old-name.
5. Last, run `git fetch --prune MWNG` to update your own repository with the new names.

If you don't need to preserve one version of the name, it's much easier: just do the deletion push on the "bad" name, plus the final fetch-with-prune-option to un-confuse your own Git.